# Importing Arabic Numbers from Excel to SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, numbers, arabic

I have a table in Excel with two columns:

```
Arabic Numbers
English Numbers
```

I imported it to SQL, the arabic numbers were displayed in English characters

How can I import them in arabic to SQL?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is your Arabic Numbers column nvarchar ?make it

Comment: @KumarHarsh Of course. I think the problem is from my excel file. The values look in Arabic but when I double click the cell, its value is in english...

Comment: how are you importing ?sql server import tool or using c#,vb.net etc in between ?

Comment: No, no ADO. Importing directly from SQL

Answer (score 0):

Alter your arabic number column as,

```
Alter table your_tablename alter Col1 nvarchar(max) collate Arabic_CI_AS not null
```

and try to import again